# Is there something special about a file type input that makes it not able to find?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm looking to add files to an `<input type="file">`

Here is a snippet of the html

```
 <span class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-file"> #found
    <span class="blahicon blahicon-upload"></span>
    Browse
    <input type="file" data-bind="value: fileName, event: { change: uploadImagesOnChange }"
    accept="blah/txt" multiple=""> #not found
 </span>
```

and here's the capybara and ruby

```
 within_frame('frame1') do
   within_frame('frame2') do
     within(:xpath, [containing span xpath]) do  # finds this
       find(:xpath, './/*[@type="file"]').send_keys('C:\Users\...\blah.txt') #ElementNotFound
     end
   end
 end
```

I see no hidden block and it's super scoped.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I should also add that the find selector works in firebug

Comment: If you look in a real browser you'll probably see the actual file input is hidden or transparent - what's the exact error?

Comment: View source over inspect? ElementNotFound, I'll post it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `within(:xpath, [containing span xpath])` can you directly check the xpath of input like: `has_xpath?(".//span[contains(text(),'Browse')]/input")` 
and if it is returning true then try with using 
`find(:xpath, ".//span[contains(text(),'Browse')]/input").send_keys ('C:\Users\...\blah.txt')`

If you are aware about the 'pry' gem then you can debug this thing by trying various xpath combinations instead of just running the whole script, So you will get to know the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mistake in your xpath

`.//*[@type="file"]`

Change to

`.//*[@type='file']`

as browser can detect attribute value with double quotes(" ") but inside script you need to use it in single quote (' ')

Also can make different combinations of your XPath like

`//input[@type='file']`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the class `btn-file` on the wrapper class, it's probable you're using Bootstrap and one of the "standard" methods to hide the actual file input element so that it can be style the same across multiple browsers.  There are a number of ways of hiding the button from just setting display:none on it to the more "modern" method of expanding it to the same size as the replacement button and seeting it's opacity to 0 so it become a transparent overlay on the replacement.

The basic strategy to dealing with this kind of setup in Capybara is to use `execute_script` to make the element visible first and then use `attach_file` or `set` as normal.  For instance if your site is using the opacity method of hiding the file element you could do something like

```
within_frame('frame1') do
  within_frame('frame2') do
    within(:xpath, [containing span xpath]) do  # finds this
      file_input = find(:file, visible: :all)
      page.driver.browser.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).css('opacity',1)", file_input.native)          
      file_input.set('C:\Users\...\blah.txt')
    end
  end
end
```

Note - this code assumes you're using jQuery in your page and will only work with the selenium driver since it uses seleniums driver specific ability to pass elements from capybara to selenium in the execute_script call. If not using jQuery the JS will need to change and if using another driver you would need to find the element in the JS script using DOM methods and then modify its opacity.